# Find a class with mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

There is an easy to find a div inside a $(document) with mouseover?
I have 3 divs like this:

```
<div class="container1" style="height:100px; width: 100%; border: 3px solid red">
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="container3">
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container4" style="height:100px; width: 100%; border: 3px solid green">
  <div class='container5'>
    
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container6" style="height:100px; width: 100%; border: 3px solid black">
  <div class='container7'>
    
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container8" style="height:100px; width: 100%; border: 3px solid yellow">
  <div class='container9'>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

With a simple console.log() I need to find when I move mouse over the container1 and the container4 only.

Here is a work in progress fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net

Thank you!

Comment: Fix you fiddle. or better use Code Sample [edit] (`{}` button)

Comment: PS: Don't use Unique selector for ClassNames - ClassNames should be general and common. Use ID instead if and only if that's a needed case.

Comment: Did you save your jsfiddle?  Link is broken.  Better to include in a *snippet* `[<>]` (or code sample would suffice).

Comment: @freedomn-m you're right, sorry. This is the saved jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/1hmnsj68/

Comment: Well that's just your html, hardly a "work in progress"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `.on()` specifying the event and element's classes like the following way:

```js
$(document).on('mouseover', '.container1,.container4', function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('class'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container1" style="height:100px; width: 100%; border: 3px solid red">
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="container3">
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container4" style="height:100px; width: 100%; border: 3px solid green">
  <div class='container5'>
    
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container6" style="height:100px; width: 100%; border: 3px solid black">
  <div class='container7'>
    
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container8" style="height:100px; width: 100%; border: 3px solid yellow">
  <div class='container9'>
    
  </div>
</div>
```